# Tablet [Element 7v3] - cannot be resetted (Technical problem)

Tags: recovery-mode, tablet, usb-debugging

I trying to reset Element 7v3.
It cannot enter recovery mode when is turned off. It has only 3 buttons at all [Volume Up, Volume Down, Power Button](no touch buttons like home).

I tried:
Holding - `[Volume Up] + [Power]`
Holding - `[Volume Down] + [Power]`

I entered recovery mode from the `settings/backup` and recovery (Reboot and enter recovery mode).
It reboots and shows the recovery mode, the `[Volume Up]` and `[Volume Down]` works, but the `[Power]` button doesn't make any actions. I think it must execute "select" option, but nothing happening. I tried all possible keys combinations to select "wipe data/factory reset" - with no luck.

When I was in the recovery mode (entered from the settings menu), I was unable to exit the recovery mode screen.
For example:
Cannot turn off the phone form the `[Power]` button, I cannot select any option in the list.
The tablet was turned off because battery was too low. (the battery was full when I entered the recovery mode).

Do you have any ideas how to reset it?

I accept any ways, including debugging within USB or Android SDK fix. I am not very familiar with Android, but I good experience in web development.

*I wanna reset it cuz I was unable to create or use an existing Gmail account, I cannot download google play applications and I have many other problems.*

Comment: @Firelord didn't know about "ADB", I will get familiar with it, I will try it Thx

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped about ADB. Got it wrong. Anyhow, does your tablet supports OTG. I checked my device's recovery whether it detects mouse or not. It does but not the cursor, however, it gets the job done. Downside is that the recovery is a custom one. IDT whether stock recovery will work for you as well. So, do you have OTG support as well as the cable?

Comment: Would not Factory Reset inside **Settings** under Android OS work for you in Android?

Comment: I've just flashed ClockworkMod to my O4X and was sitting in the same boat: while in previous versions the power button was used to select, they seem to have switched that to the home button (which my device luckily has, though as soft-button). Reading ADB: Yes, a reset should be possible that way. AFAIR `fastboot -w` (wipe) accomplishes that. Please check with our [fastboot tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) for details.